# Zoho Deluge Compare List

Tags: zoho, zoho-deluge, deluge

We are working a project with deluge. I stuck in here and i need a help;

We are using a zoho projects and we are working a transfer other Zoho projects to my Zoho projects
now i stucked in update part. im getting tasklists both side and i need to compare tasklists if matches go and check tasks if not matches create tasklists. How can compare tasklists any one can help me ?

```
//get client tasklist
clientTaskListApi = invokeUrl
[
    url :project_portal_url + trial_portal_id + "/projects/" + project_query_id + "/tasklists/"
    type :GET
    headers:{"Authorization":"Bearer " + client_access_token}
];
clientTaskList=clientTaskListApi.get("tasklists");

// get my tasklist
myTaskListApi = invokeUrl
[
    url :my_portal_url + my_portal_id + "/projects/" + project_query_id + "/tasklists/"
    type :GET
    headers:{"Authorization":"Bearer " + my_access_token}
];
myTaskList=myTaskListApi.get("tasklists");


for each clienttasklistsloop in clientTaskList
{
    clientTaskName = clienttasklistsloop.get("name");
    clientTaskid = clienttasklistsloop.get("id");

    for each mytasklistloop in myTaskList
    {
            myTaskName = mytasklistloop.get("name");
            myTaskid = mytasklistloop.get("id");
            if ( myTaskName == clientTaskName ) 
            {
                info "do anything"
            }
    }
}
```

im trying this but this is not good and correct.

Comment: On initial look, your code seems okay.  Could you add some description of what is going wrong?